# beginners python error: reading and adding numbers from a file

Tags: python, string, int

so i'm trying to pull numbers from a file numbers.txt and add them together.  The program can currently pull the numbers one at a time and print them spaced out on one line.  I now need it to total all of the values. The numbers in the file are:
9
19
15
17
5
17
The total should be 82 but it will only add the two number 17's and output 34

def main():

```
numfile = open('numbers.txt', 'r')

for line in numfile:
    line = line.rstrip('\n')

    print (line, end=' ')
    total = int(line)
    total += total

print ("\nEnd of file")   
print (total)

numfile.close()
```

main()

Comment: OK, thanks. I've removed the total = 0 and turned line into an integer.. but the program is only adding 2 numbers from the file not all 6.. but it will print all 6

Comment: No, you're still reinitializing `total` every time through the loop. Try setting `total = 0` *before* the `for line in` statement.

Comment: Ok thanks.  I tried that.  i'm still getting 34 as an answer instead of 82

Answer (score 1):

You have *two* problems. The first is as other answers have said - you are reading in *strings*. You need to convert those to a numeric data type. This is either `int` or `float` (or if you are doing monetary values, I recommend using [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html)).

Very simply, this can be done like so:

```
total += float(line)
```

---

Second, you are resetting `total` to `0` each time you go through your `for` loop. Thus, at the end of your loop, `total` will equal the last value you read.

To correct this, pull your `total = 0` out of the loop:

```
total = 0
for line in numfile:
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

convert the string to an int:

```
total += int(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to convert `line` to an integer. At the moment, you're trying to add a string to an integer, which isn't possible. Simply wrap `line` in `int()`, like this:

```
total += int(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you the exact problem: you're adding an `int` and a `str`. The `int` is `total` and the `str` is `line`. Everything from a file is of type `str`. To fix the error, do `total += int(line)`.

You will also need to initialize `total` *before* you start the loop, or it'll keep resetting to zero and leave you with just the final value.

Overall, you can streamline the code as follows:

```
with open('numbers.txt') as f:
    print(sum(map(int, f)))
```

This maps the file iterator to `int`s, then adds them with `sum`, then prints it with `print`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize `total` *before* the loop, not inside it. You're also doubling `total` instead of accumulating it. Try this:

```
def main():

numfile = open('numbers.txt', 'r')

total = 0  # initialize here

for line in numfile:
    line = line.rstrip('\n')

    print (line, end=' ')
    total += int(line)  #/ accumulate here

print ("\nEnd of file")   
print (total)

numfile.close()

main()
```

Note that `total` is modified **once before the beginning** of the loop and **once inside** the loop.

Comment: i have run the program with total initialized above the loop, and with "total = 0" removed.  I am still getting an output of 34 but not 82.

Comment: Compare my solution to yours line-by-line and see if you can spot the difference.

Comment: Awesome.  I appreciate your help.  I am new to this site.  Is their any way you get credit for helping?

Comment: Mark my answer "Accepted" by clicking on the big check mark to the left of it. Glad I could help.